# Anaconda Error - module 'brotli' has no attribute 'error'

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I updated anaconda using Anaconda Command Prompt.

After update whenever I run any command ex: conda info or conda list I get the below error

```
module 'brotli' has no attribute 'error'
```

I would Really appreciate any help on this! Not sure how it solve it

Answer (score 52):

I solved this issue by commenting lines 376 & 377 in the file

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py
```

[image]

and then install brotli library by running either

```
pip install brotli
```

or

```
conda install brotli
```

After successful installation, uncomment above lines.
Do whatever you want now. Error should not come.

Comment: Your solution was the only one that worked for me with miniconda3.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. None of them worked. So I found this solution.

Comment: Just want to add that depending on the version, the line numbers may be different. I followed the error message `DECODER_ERROR_CLASSES += (brotli.error,)
AttributeError: module 'brotli' has no attribute 'error'`, found the code, commented out this line and the "if" clause before this. For me this was line 390.

Comment: I ran into this today, but I don't use conda. This answer worked with a small modification (in Python 3.10.2, it's on line 390) `# DECODER_ERROR_CLASSES += (brotli.error,)\npass`

Comment: @Shrirang -  Thanks you saved my day.  My location is little bit different.  On close analysis of the error message I am able to figure it out.  Even though the other one is also present.  I have to modify C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py

Comment: @Subramanian Yeah. The location may have changed. I solved this 2 years ago.

Comment: I used a combination of this and kiran-parte's solution. 1. Commented the lines causing the error. The path was different for me since I am using a user install of miniconda. 2. `conda install -c conda-forge brotlipy` 3. Uncommented the lines causing the error.

Comment: In Feb. 2024, this solution still works (and this error still occurs.)

Answer (score 34):

I solved the issue by installing `urllib3`

Just open the terminal and type:

```
conda install -c anaconda urllib3
```

or you can also try:

```
conda install -c conda-forge brotlipy
```

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge brotlipy` worked for me when `conda install brotli` did not

Answer (score 10):

I solved the issue by installing brotlipy

Just open the terminal and type:

```
conda install -c anaconda brotlipy
```

Answer (score 5):

the commands below works for me somehow:

```
pip install -U urllib3
pip install -U brotlipy
```

Comment: I hate going into library files and making adjustments if I do not absolutely have to.  This worked perfect for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yet another variation on a fix: for me (Windows 10, minconda3), installing `brotli` via pip fixed the problem.

Since I could not use any of these `conda` commands (`list`, `update`, `install`), the solution had to come from `pip`! Even though the error message pointed to `urllib3`, I first reinstalled `brotli` with `pip`, then performed my initial `conda list` command flawlessly... so I did not update or modify `urllib3` in any way, which is kind of strange!

Comment: I have the same setup (Win10/miniforge) and this did *not* fix the issue for me. `pip install brotli` worked, but did not fix the error. all of the other solutions listed return the same error as OP when run.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by the following way

```
1- comment the lines 
2- conda install brotli
3- run anaconda like normal
```

i kept the lines 376 and 377 commented

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, but I was able to fix it by simply installing brotli.

```
conda install brotli
```

Brotli v1.0.7 fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This didn't help me. I get the same error (`module 'brotli' has no attribute 'error'`) when running `conda install brotli`.

Furthermore, no change after successfully running `pip install brotli`.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

1. commented out the recommended lines above.
2. launched the anaconda navigator
3. searched for any packages with "**brotli**"
4. installed / updated all of those
5. uncommented out the lines

Navigator is back working but not sure of any other downstream issues yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just install again in the terminal/prompt the following:

`python -m pip install brotlicffi`

Then you can `update conda` or if you want as soon as the
first was reinstalled you can already open the navigator

Answer (score -2):

I solved this issue by commenting lines 389 & 390 in the file

```
C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\response.py
```

and then install brotli library by running

```
pip install brotli
```