# Conda AttributeError: module 'brotli' has no attribute 'error' after update

Tags: python, module, conda, brotli

I just run the command `conda update conda`. After that, all of my commands gives `AttributeError: module 'brotli' has no attribute 'error'`. I searched for solutions but none works. [Anaconda Error - module 'brotli' has no attribute 'error'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61881121/anaconda-error-module-brotli-has-no-attribute-error) seems a reasonable answer but my anaconda3/lib directory does not contain a site-packages folder.
The lib folder contains the following.

```
cmake                                     libicudata.so.72.1                  libQt5Designer.so.5                     libQt5X11Extras.so.5
cups                                      libicui18n.so                       libQt5Designer.so.5.15                  libQt5X11Extras.so.5.15
cyrillic_and_mic.so                       libicui18n.so.72                    libQt5Designer.so.5.15.8                libQt5X11Extras.so.5.15.8
dbus-1.0                                  libicui18n.so.72.1                  libQt5DeviceDiscoverySupport.a          libQt5XcbQpa.prl
dict_snowball.so                          libicuio.so                         libQt5DeviceDiscoverySupport.prl        libQt5XcbQpa.so
euc2004_sjis2004.so                       libicuio.so.72                      libQt5EdidSupport.a                     libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
euc_cn_and_mic.so                         libicuio.so.72.1                    libQt5EdidSupport.prl                   libQt5XcbQpa.so.5.15
euc_jp_and_sjis.so                        libicutest.so                       libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.prl        libQt5XcbQpa.so.5.15.8
euc_kr_and_mic.so                         libicutest.so.72                    libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so         libQt5XkbCommonSupport.a
euc_tw_and_big5.so                        libicutest.so.72.1                  libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so.5       libQt5XkbCommonSupport.prl
gettext                                   libicutu.so                         libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so.5.15    libQt5XmlPatterns.prl
girepository-1.0                          libicutu.so.72                      libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so.5.15.8  libQt5XmlPatterns.so
glib-2.0                                  libicutu.so.72.1                    libQt5EglFsKmsSupport.prl               libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5
gstreamer-1.0                             libicuuc.so                         libQt5EglFsKmsSupport.so                libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5.15
icu                                       libicuuc.so.72                      libQt5EglFsKmsSupport.so.5              libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5.15.8
itcl4.2.2                                 libicuuc.so.72.1                    libQt5EglFsKmsSupport.so.5.15           libQt5Xml.prl
krb5                                      libitm.so                           libQt5EglFsKmsSupport.so.5.15.8         libQt5Xml.so
latin2_and_win1250.so                     libitm.so.1                         libQt5EglSupport.a                      libQt5Xml.so.5
latin_and_mic.so                          libitm.so.1.0.0                     libQt5EglSupport.prl                    libQt5Xml.so.5.15
libarchive.a                              libjpeg.a                           libQt5EventDispatcherSupport.a          libQt5Xml.so.5.15.8
libarchive.so                             libjpeg.so                          libQt5EventDispatcherSupport.prl        libquadmath.so
libarchive.so.13                          libjpeg.so.8                        libQt5FbSupport.a                       libquadmath.so.0
libarchive.so.13.6.2                      libjpeg.so.8.2.2                    libQt5FbSupport.prl                     libquadmath.so.0.0.0
libasound.so                              libk5crypto.so                      libQt5FontDatabaseSupport.a             libreadline.so
libasound.so.2                            libk5crypto.so.3                    libQt5FontDatabaseSupport.prl           libreadline.so.8
libasound.so.2.0.0                        libk5crypto.so.3.1                  libQt5Gamepad.prl                       libreadline.so.8.2
libasprintf.a                             libkadm5clnt_mit.so                 libQt5Gamepad.so                        libRemarks.so.16
libasprintf.so                            libkadm5clnt_mit.so.12              libQt5Gamepad.so.5                      libsharpyuv.so
libasprintf.so.0                          libkadm5clnt_mit.so.12.0            libQt5Gamepad.so.5.15                   libsharpyuv.so.0
libasprintf.so.0.0.0                      libkadm5clnt.so                     libQt5Gamepad.so.5.15.8                 libsharpyuv.so.0.0.0
libatomic.so                              libkadm5srv_mit.so                  libQt5GlxSupport.a                      libsmime3.so
libatomic.so.1                            libkadm5srv_mit.so.12               libQt5GlxSupport.prl                    libSM.so
libatomic.so.1.2.0                        libkadm5srv_mit.so.12.0             libQt5Gui.prl                           libSM.so.6
libatopology.so                           libkadm5srv.so                      libQt5Gui.so                            libSM.so.6.0.1
libatopology.so.2                         libkdb5.so                          libQt5Gui.so.5                          libsndfile.so
libatopology.so.2.0.0                     libkdb5.so.10                       libQt5Gui.so.5.15                       libsndfile.so.1
libattr.so                                libkdb5.so.10.0                     libQt5Gui.so.5.15.8                     libsndfile.so.1.0.35
libattr.so.1                              libkeyutils.a                       libQt5Help.prl                          libsoftokn3.chk
libattr.so.1.1.2501                       libkeyutils.so                      libQt5Help.so                           libsoftokn3.so
libblas.so                                libkeyutils.so.1                    libQt5Help.so.5                         libsqlite3.so
libblas.so.3                              libkeyutils.so.1.9                  libQt5Help.so.5.15                      libsqlite3.so.0
libbrotlicommon.so                        libkrad.so                          libQt5Help.so.5.15.8                    libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
libbrotlicommon.so.1                      libkrad.so.0                        libQt5InputSupport.a                    libssl3.so
libbrotlicommon.so.1.0.9                  libkrad.so.0.0                      libQt5InputSupport.prl                  libssl.so
libbrotlidec.so                           libkrb5.so                          libQt5KmsSupport.a                      libssl.so.3
libbrotlidec.so.1                         libkrb5.so.3                        libQt5KmsSupport.prl                    libstdc++.so
libbrotlidec.so.1.0.9                     libkrb5.so.3.3                      libQt5Location.prl                      libstdc++.so.6
libbrotlienc.so                           libkrb5support.so                   libQt5Location.so                       libstdc++.so.6.0.30
libbrotlienc.so.1                         libkrb5support.so.0                 libQt5Location.so.5                     libsyn123.so
libbrotlienc.so.1.0.9                     libkrb5support.so.0.1               libQt5Location.so.5.15                  libsyn123.so.0
libbz2.a                                  liblapack.so                        libQt5Location.so.5.15.8                libsyn123.so.0.1.5
libbz2.so                                 liblapack.so.3                      libQt5MultimediaGstTools.prl            libsystemd.so.0
libbz2.so.1.0                             liblcms2.so                         libQt5MultimediaGstTools.so             libsystemd.so.0.36.0
libbz2.so.1.0.8                           liblcms2.so.2                       libQt5MultimediaGstTools.so.5           libtcl8.6.so
libcairo.a                                liblcms2.so.2.0.15                  libQt5MultimediaGstTools.so.5.15        libtclstub8.6.a
libcairo-gobject.a                        libLerc.so                          libQt5MultimediaGstTools.so.5.15.8      libtextstyle.a
libcairo-gobject.so                       libLerc.so.4                        libQt5Multimedia.prl                    libtextstyle.so
libcairo-gobject.so.2                     libLIEF.so                          libQt5MultimediaQuick.prl               libtextstyle.so.0
libcairo-gobject.so.2.11600.0             libLLVM-16.so                       libQt5MultimediaQuick.so                libtextstyle.so.0.1.2
libcairo-script-interpreter.a             libLTO.so.16                        libQt5MultimediaQuick.so.5              libtiff.so
libcairo-script-interpreter.so            liblz4.so                           libQt5MultimediaQuick.so.5.15           libtiff.so.6
libcairo-script-interpreter.so.2          liblz4.so.1                         libQt5MultimediaQuick.so.5.15.8         libtiff.so.6.0.0
libcairo-script-interpreter.so.2.11600.0  liblz4.so.1.9.4                     libQt5Multimedia.so                     libtiffxx.so
libcairo.so                               liblzma.so                          libQt5Multimedia.so.5                   libtiffxx.so.6
libcairo.so.2                             liblzma.so.5                        libQt5Multimedia.so.5.15                libtiffxx.so.6.0.0
libcairo.so.2.11600.0                     liblzma.so.5.2.6                    libQt5Multimedia.so.5.15.8              libtinfo.so
libcap.a                                  liblzo2.a                           libQt5MultimediaWidgets.prl             libtinfo.so.6
libcap.so                                 liblzo2.so                          libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so              libtinfo.so.6.3
libcap.so.2                               liblzo2.so.2                        libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so.5            libtinfow.so
libcap.so.2.67                            liblzo2.so.2.0.0                    libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so.5.15         libtinfow.so.6
libcblas.so                               libmenu.so                          libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so.5.15.8       libtinfow.so.6.3
libcblas.so.3                             libmenu.so.6                        libQt5NetworkAuth.prl                   libtk8.6.so
libcharset.a                              libmenu.so.6.3                      libQt5NetworkAuth.so                    libtkstub8.6.a
libcharset.so                             libmenuw.so                         libQt5NetworkAuth.so.5                  libturbojpeg.a
libcharset.so.1                           libmenuw.so.6                       libQt5NetworkAuth.so.5.15               libturbojpeg.so
libcharset.so.1.0.0                       libmenuw.so.6.3                     libQt5NetworkAuth.so.5.15.8             libturbojpeg.so.0
libclang.so                               libmp3lame.a                        libQt5Network.prl                       libturbojpeg.so.0.2.0
libclang.so.13                            libmp3lame.so                       libQt5Network.so                        libuuid.a
libcom_err.so                             libmp3lame.so.0                     libQt5Network.so.5                      libuuid.so
libcom_err.so.3                           libmp3lame.so.0.0.0                 libQt5Network.so.5.15                   libuuid.so.1
libcom_err.so.3.0                         libmpg123.so                        libQt5Network.so.5.15.8                 libuuid.so.1.3.0
libcrmf.a                                 libmpg123.so.0                      libQt5Nfc.prl                           libverto.so
libcrypto.so                              libmpg123.so.0.47.0                 libQt5Nfc.so                            libverto.so.0
libcrypto.so.3                            libmysqlclient.so                   libQt5Nfc.so.5                          libverto.so.0.0
libcupsimage.so                           libmysqlclient.so.21                libQt5Nfc.so.5.15                       libvorbisenc.so
libcupsimage.so.2                         libmysqlclient.so.21.2.32           libQt5Nfc.so.5.15.8                     libvorbisenc.so.2
libcups.so                                libncurses++.a                      libQt5OpenGLExtensions.a                libvorbisenc.so.2.0.12
libcups.so.2                              libncurses.so                       libQt5OpenGLExtensions.prl              libvorbisfile.so
libdbus-1.a                               libncurses.so.6                     libQt5OpenGL.prl                        libvorbisfile.so.3
libdbus-1.so                              libncurses.so.6.3                   libQt5OpenGL.so                         libvorbisfile.so.3.3.8
libdbus-1.so.3                            libncurses++w.a                     libQt5OpenGL.so.5                       libvorbis.so
libdbus-1.so.3.24.0                       libncursesw.so                      libQt5OpenGL.so.5.15                    libvorbis.so.0
libdeflate.so                             libncursesw.so.6                    libQt5OpenGL.so.5.15.8                  libvorbis.so.0.4.9
libdeflate.so.0                           libncursesw.so.6.3                  libQt5PacketProtocol.a                  libwebpdecoder.so
libecpg.a                                 libnsl.so                           libQt5PacketProtocol.prl                libwebpdecoder.so.3
libecpg_compat.a                          libnsl.so.3                         libQt5PlatformCompositorSupport.a       libwebpdecoder.so.3.1.6
libecpg_compat.so                         libnsl.so.3.0.0                     libQt5PlatformCompositorSupport.prl     libwebpdemux.so
libecpg_compat.so.3                       libnspr4.so                         libQt5Positioning.prl                   libwebpdemux.so.2
libecpg_compat.so.3.15                    libnss3.so                          libQt5PositioningQuick.prl              libwebpdemux.so.2.0.12
libecpg.so                                libnssckbi.so                       libQt5PositioningQuick.so               libwebpmux.so
libecpg.so.6                              libnssckbi-testlib.so               libQt5PositioningQuick.so.5             libwebpmux.so.3
libecpg.so.6.15                           libnssdbm3.chk                      libQt5PositioningQuick.so.5.15          libwebpmux.so.3.0.11
libedit.so                                libnssdbm3.so                       libQt5PositioningQuick.so.5.15.8        libwebp.so
libedit.so.0                              libnsssysinit.so                    libQt5Positioning.so                    libwebp.so.7
libedit.so.0.0.63                         libnssutil3.so                      libQt5Positioning.so.5                  libwebp.so.7.1.6
libevent-2.1.so                           libogg.so                           libQt5Positioning.so.5.15               libX11.so
libevent-2.1.so.7                         libogg.so.0                         libQt5Positioning.so.5.15.8             libX11.so.6
libevent-2.1.so.7.0.1                     libogg.so.0.8.4                     libQt5PrintSupport.prl                  libX11.so.6.4.0
libevent_core-2.1.so                      libopenblasp-r0.3.21.so             libQt5PrintSupport.so                   libX11-xcb.so
libevent_core-2.1.so.7                    libopenblas.so.0                    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5                 libX11-xcb.so.1
libevent_core-2.1.so.7.0.1                libopenjp2.a                        libQt5PrintSupport.so.5.15              libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
libevent_core.so                          libopenjp2.so                       libQt5PrintSupport.so.5.15.8            libXau.so
libevent_extra-2.1.so                     libopenjp2.so.2.5.0                 libQt5Purchasing.prl                    libXau.so.6
libevent_extra-2.1.so.7                   libopenjp2.so.7                     libQt5Purchasing.so                     libXau.so.6.0.0
libevent_extra-2.1.so.7.0.1               libopus.so                          libQt5Purchasing.so.5                   libxcb-composite.so
libevent_extra.so                         libopus.so.0                        libQt5Purchasing.so.5.15                libxcb-composite.so.0
libevent_openssl-2.1.so                   libopus.so.0.8.0                    libQt5Purchasing.so.5.15.8              libxcb-composite.so.0.0.0
libevent_openssl-2.1.so.7                 libout123.so                        libQt5QmlDebug.a                        libxcb-damage.so
libevent_openssl-2.1.so.7.0.1             libout123.so.0                      libQt5QmlDebug.prl                      libxcb-damage.so.0
libevent_openssl.so                       libout123.so.0.4.7                  libQt5QmlDevTools.a                     libxcb-damage.so.0.0.0
libevent_pthreads-2.1.so                  libpanel.so                         libQt5QmlDevTools.prl                   libxcb-dpms.so
libevent_pthreads-2.1.so.7                libpanel.so.6                       libQt5QmlModels.prl                     libxcb-dpms.so.0
libevent_pthreads-2.1.so.7.0.1            libpanel.so.6.3                     libQt5QmlModels.so                      libxcb-dpms.so.0.0.0
libevent_pthreads.so                      libpanelw.so                        libQt5QmlModels.so.5                    libxcb-dri2.so
libevent.so                               libpanelw.so.6                      libQt5QmlModels.so.5.15                 libxcb-dri2.so.0
libexpat.a                                libpanelw.so.6.3                    libQt5QmlModels.so.5.15.8               libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
libexpat.so                               libpcre2-16.so                      libQt5Qml.prl                           libxcb-dri3.so
libexpat.so.1                             libpcre2-16.so.0                    libQt5Qml.so                            libxcb-dri3.so.0
libexpat.so.1.8.10                        libpcre2-16.so.0.11.0               libQt5Qml.so.5                          libxcb-dri3.so.0.1.0
libffi.a                                  libpcre2-32.so                      libQt5Qml.so.5.15                       libxcb-ewmh.a
libffi.so                                 libpcre2-32.so.0                    libQt5Qml.so.5.15.8                     libxcb-ewmh.so
libffi.so.8                               libpcre2-32.so.0.11.0               libQt5QmlWorkerScript.prl               libxcb-ewmh.so.2
libffi.so.8.1.0                           libpcre2-8.so                       libQt5QmlWorkerScript.so                libxcb-ewmh.so.2.0.0
libFLAC++.so                              libpcre2-8.so.0                     libQt5QmlWorkerScript.so.5              libxcb-glx.so
libFLAC.so                                libpcre2-8.so.0.11.0                libQt5QmlWorkerScript.so.5.15           libxcb-glx.so.0
libFLAC++.so.10                           libpcre2-posix.so                   libQt5QmlWorkerScript.so.5.15.8         libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
libFLAC++.so.10.0.0                       libpcre2-posix.so.3                 libQt5Quick3DAssetImport.prl            libxcb-icccm.a
libFLAC.so.12                             libpcre2-posix.so.3.0.2             libQt5Quick3DAssetImport.so             libxcb-icccm.so
libFLAC.so.12.0.0                         libpgcommon.a                       libQt5Quick3DAssetImport.so.5           libxcb-icccm.so.4
libfontconfig.a                           libpgcommon_shlib.a                 libQt5Quick3DAssetImport.so.5.15        libxcb-icccm.so.4.0.0
libfontconfig.so                          libpgfeutils.a                      libQt5Quick3DAssetImport.so.5.15.8      libxcb-image.a
libfontconfig.so.1                        libpgport.a                         libQt5Quick3D.prl                       libxcb-image.so
libfontconfig.so.1.13.0                   libpgport_shlib.a                   libQt5Quick3DRender.prl                 libxcb-image.so.0
libform.so                                libpgtypes.a                        libQt5Quick3DRender.so                  libxcb-image.so.0.0.0
libform.so.6                              libpgtypes.so                       libQt5Quick3DRender.so.5                libxcb-keysyms.a
libform.so.6.3                            libpgtypes.so.3                     libQt5Quick3DRender.so.5.15             libxcb-keysyms.so
libformw.so                               libpgtypes.so.3.15                  libQt5Quick3DRender.so.5.15.8           libxcb-keysyms.so.1
libformw.so.6                             libpixman-1.a                       libQt5Quick3DRuntimeRender.prl          libxcb-keysyms.so.1.0.0
libformw.so.6.3                           libpixman-1.so                      libQt5Quick3DRuntimeRender.so           libxcb-present.so
libfreebl3.chk                            libpixman-1.so.0                    libQt5Quick3DRuntimeRender.so.5         libxcb-present.so.0
libfreebl3.so                             libpixman-1.so.0.40.0               libQt5Quick3DRuntimeRender.so.5.15      libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
libfreeblpriv3.chk                        libplc4.so                          libQt5Quick3DRuntimeRender.so.5.15.8    libxcb-randr.so
libfreeblpriv3.so                         libplds4.so                         libQt5Quick3D.so                        libxcb-randr.so.0
libfreetype.a                             libpng16.a                          libQt5Quick3D.so.5                      libxcb-randr.so.0.1.0
libfreetype.so                            libpng16.so                         libQt5Quick3D.so.5.15                   libxcb-record.so
libfreetype.so.6                          libpng16.so.16                      libQt5Quick3D.so.5.15.8                 libxcb-record.so.0
libfreetype.so.6.18.3                     libpng16.so.16.39.0                 libQt5Quick3DUtils.prl                  libxcb-record.so.0.0.0
libgcc_s.so                               libpng.a                            libQt5Quick3DUtils.so                   libxcb-render.so
libgcc_s.so.1                             libpng.so                           libQt5Quick3DUtils.so.5                 libxcb-render.so.0
libgcrypt.so                              libpq.a                             libQt5Quick3DUtils.so.5.15              libxcb-render.so.0.0.0
libgcrypt.so.20                           libpq.so                            libQt5Quick3DUtils.so.5.15.8            libxcb-render-util.a
libgcrypt.so.20.4.1                       libpq.so.5                          libQt5QuickControls2.prl                libxcb-render-util.so
libgettextlib-0.21.1.so                   libpq.so.5.15                       libQt5QuickControls2.so                 libxcb-render-util.so.0
libgettextlib.so                          libpqwalreceiver.so                 libQt5QuickControls2.so.5               libxcb-render-util.so.0.0.0
libgettextpo.a                            libpsx.a                            libQt5QuickControls2.so.5.15            libxcb-res.so
libgettextpo.so                           libpsx.so                           libQt5QuickControls2.so.5.15.8          libxcb-res.so.0
libgettextpo.so.0                         libpsx.so.2                         libQt5QuickParticles.prl                libxcb-res.so.0.0.0
libgettextpo.so.0.5.8                     libpsx.so.2.67                      libQt5QuickParticles.so                 libxcb-screensaver.so
libgettextsrc-0.21.1.so                   libpulse-mainloop-glib.so           libQt5QuickParticles.so.5               libxcb-screensaver.so.0
libgettextsrc.so                          libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0         libQt5QuickParticles.so.5.15            libxcb-screensaver.so.0.0.0
libgfortran.so                            libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0.0.6     libQt5QuickParticles.so.5.15.8          libxcb-shape.so
libgfortran.so.5                          libpulse-simple.so                  libQt5Quick.prl                         libxcb-shape.so.0
libgfortran.so.5.0.0                      libpulse-simple.so.0                libQt5QuickShapes.prl                   libxcb-shape.so.0.0.0
libgio-2.0.so                             libpulse-simple.so.0.1.1            libQt5QuickShapes.so                    libxcb-shm.so
libgio-2.0.so.0                           libpulse.so                         libQt5QuickShapes.so.5                  libxcb-shm.so.0
libgio-2.0.so.0.7600.2                    libpulse.so.0                       libQt5QuickShapes.so.5.15               libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0
libglib-2.0.so                            libpulse.so.0.24.2                  libQt5QuickShapes.so.5.15.8             libxcb.so
libglib-2.0.so.0                          libpython3.9.so                     libQt5Quick.so                          libxcb.so.1
libglib-2.0.so.0.7600.2                   libpython3.9.so.1.0                 libQt5Quick.so.5                        libxcb.so.1.1.0
libgmodule-2.0.so                         libpython3.so                       libQt5Quick.so.5.15                     libxcb-sync.so
libgmodule-2.0.so.0                       libQt53DAnimation.prl               libQt5Quick.so.5.15.8                   libxcb-sync.so.1
libgmodule-2.0.so.0.7600.2                libQt53DAnimation.so                libQt5QuickTemplates2.prl               libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
libgobject-2.0.so                         libQt53DAnimation.so.5              libQt5QuickTemplates2.so                libxcb-util.a
libgobject-2.0.so.0                       libQt53DAnimation.so.5.15           libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5              libxcb-util.so
libgobject-2.0.so.0.7600.2                libQt53DAnimation.so.5.15.8         libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5.15           libxcb-util.so.1
libgomp.so                                libQt53DCore.prl                    libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5.15.8         libxcb-util.so.1.0.0
libgomp.so.1                              libQt53DCore.so                     libQt5QuickTest.prl                     libxcb-xf86dri.so
libgomp.so.1.0.0                          libQt53DCore.so.5                   libQt5QuickTest.so                      libxcb-xf86dri.so.0
libgpg-error.so                           libQt53DCore.so.5.15                libQt5QuickTest.so.5                    libxcb-xf86dri.so.0.0.0
libgpg-error.so.0                         libQt53DCore.so.5.15.8              libQt5QuickTest.so.5.15                 libxcb-xfixes.so
libgpg-error.so.0.33.1                    libQt53DExtras.prl                  
...
```

Also any kind of command with conda gives the same error so `conda install brotli` solutions do not work. How can I proceed? (I am in a remote linux server)

Comment: Should be under `anaconda/lib/python*/site-packages`. In the answer they have Windows system, which may have slightly different organization.

Comment: I found now, thanks

Comment: Same error here on Windows after updating conda. I commented the two lines `if brotli is not None: DECODER_ERROR_CLASSES += (brotli.error,)` in site-packages\urllib3\response.py and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py` tries to `import brotlicffi as brotli` and then tries `import brotli`, which yields `brotli.error AttributeError: module 'brotli' has no attribute 'error'.`

`pip install brotlicffi` fixes the error in conda.

Here are the versions I ended up with. Upgrading conda removed brotlipy-0.7.0-py310h2bbff1b_1002 and added several brotli 1.0.9 pieces, perhaps missing as least one.

```
conda list | grep brotli
brotli                    1.0.9                hcfcfb64_8    conda-forge
brotli-bin                1.0.9                hcfcfb64_8    conda-forge
brotlicffi                1.0.9.2                  pypi_0    pypi
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                hcfcfb64_8    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                hcfcfb64_8    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                hcfcfb64_8    conda-forge
```

With conda working again, `conda install brotlicffi` cleans up the environment. Expect the following conda complaint; it will install enum34 to fix. You may have to repeat `conda install brotlicffi`

```
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - pypi/pypi::brotlicffi==1.0.9.2=pypi_0
```

`conda upgrade --all -n base` should work normally.